# preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2 PHP

Tags: php, callback

i am trying to use the preg_replace_callback but i am keep getting an error.

My goal is to if there is any (-) in the input, so it actually -1 value from the input.

For example ---

**If the request value is "Iphone -5" it should be "Iphone 4"**

```
public function justTestAction($string) {

    $string = "Iphone -5";
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/-\d+/', 'callback', $string);

    function callback($matches) {
        return abs($matches[0]) - 1;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

My expected Output ---

```
Expected Output -Iphone 4
```

But i am keep getting this error ---

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'callback', to
>   be a valid callback

Anyone knows how i can fix this issue !!!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `callback` function is in a class method. If you change your code to this it should work fine:

```
public function justTestAction($string) {

    $string = "Iphone -5";
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/-\d+/', function($matches){
                  return abs($matches[0]) - 1;
              }, $string);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it like as

```
function justTestAction($string) {
    $callback = function ($matches) {
        return abs($matches[0]) - 1;
    };
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/-\d+/', $callback, $string);
    return $result;
}
echo justTestAction("Iphone -5");
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/448866)